# PromQL k8s node count

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I am able to count number of nodes that are currently active on my Kubernetes cluster with

```
count(count by (instance)(node_boot_time_seconds))
```

I need a way to create a table with information like

Nodes uptime greater than 1 day:   X nodes
Nodes uptime greater than 2 days:  X nodes
Nodes uptime greater than 3 days:  X nodes

Any help is really appreciated

I tried use offset but didn't helped much like

```
sum(kube_node_info offset 1d)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the number of nodes with uptime exceeding one day:

```
count(
   (time() - node_boot_time_seconds) > 24*3600
)
```

If you need the number of nodes with uptime bigger than `N` days, then just multiply `24*3600` by `N` in the query above.

Comment: Thanks! 
This resolved for 24h but now I have a item.

When I list  greater than 48h will also grab the ones that are on greater of 24h, but if I want just nodes that are greater than 48h and not the aggregate with older than 24h together.